# Toggle Menu Like Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, navigation

I am wanting to make a responsive menu like used in Twitter Bootstrap but I'm not wanting to use bootstrap. This is for a small project and I don't need to use the entire framework. I know it's done with custom data tags and jquery but I'm not sure how.

--

I am wanting to learn how to make the toggle menu. I know how to make it responsive, but I don't know how to make the menu items open and close.

Comment: Even for small projects bootstrap is simple to use. Unless you want to learn how to do it yourself. In that case, please provide more details on what behaviour of the bootstrap navbar you want to create yourself.

Comment: Keep in mind that the Bootstrap build can be customized to only include the components that are useful to you: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ and http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/customize.html

Answer (score 0):

Heres the basics. if you have an object that you want to show or hide you simply add the class and then use either of the following css display:none; or visibility:none;

```
.nav{
 width:960px;
 }

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 300px) { 
    .nav{
    width:300px;
    }

}
```